# Why is my array turning into a bunch of zeros except the last value?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the amount of 3's in the inputed array but instead it comes up with zero or one, so I placed System.out.print to see what my array is and it was all zeros except the last value.
I need the array to keep all of its values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunArray1 {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static String input, command;
    private static int a, b, i, j;
    private static int[] inputArray;
    private static int total, count;

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        System.out.println("Enter A Command ::");
        System.out.println("1. PNumber - Your Numbers!");
        System.out.println("2. LCount - Your Lucky Numbers!");
        System.out.println("3. LTotal - Your Lucky Total!");
        command = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("PNumber")){
            Coverter();
            purifiedNumbers(inputArray);
        }
        if (command.equals("LCount")){
            Coverter();
            luckyCount(inputArray);
            System.out.println("Your Lucky Number Count is "+count);
        }
        if (command.equals("LTotal")){
            Coverter();
            luckyTotal(inputArray);
        }
    }
    private static void purifiedNumbers(int[] e){

    }

    private static int luckyCount(int[] e){
        for (i = 0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println((int)inputArray[i]);
            if (inputArray[i] == 3){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static void luckyTotal(int[] e) {
        for (i = 0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
            for(j = 3; j<inputArray.length; j++){
                total += inputArray[j];
                if(j == 5){
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }

    private static int[] Coverter(){
        System.out.println("Enter Your Life Numbers! ::");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        String[]Covert = input.split(" ");
        for (a = 0; a<Covert.length; a++){
            inputArray = new int[Covert.length];
            inputArray[a] = Integer.parseInt(Covert[a]);
        }
        return inputArray;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the array initialization outside the loop,

```
inputArray = new int[Covert.length];
for (a = 0; a<Covert.length; a++){
    // inputArray = new int[Covert.length];
    inputArray[a] = Integer.parseInt(Covert[a]);
}
```

Or you'll throw away the previous instance (with its values) on every iteration. And only have a value in the last position (as you describe in your question).

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realized that I had placed it there.